# App rejected in the Review from the Appstore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

**Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase**

> Your app unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store, which is not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> Specifically, your app unlocks a paid subscription via credit card payment.

Comment: Probably, you should move the subscription portion redirected to a browser.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: While Apple is ready to answer your question upon request, you should contact it, to get a solution

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar that means,you are telling all the  subscription portion like choosing plan,billing information and credit card payment UI  redirected to a browser.If yes then this will violates Apple guidlines please guide me

Comment: @DileepKumar example is Adobe's CC plan. Same in Microsoft too. You can subscribe to Microsoft 365 plan or Adobe CC in PC/any device. Both of them, provide Apple's In-App purchase feature as well inside app. But if your adobe/microsoft id is activated with their subscription outside app, it still reflects in app too.

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar thanks for answer...But I want to clarify something I have created subscription plan UI ,Billing UI and credit card payment UI in my iOS App and through the services I am sending data to my local server they are using PayPal gateway for payment in Backend and completing Payment.and after payment successful they are notify me.so All these things we are handling through the web services..pls guide me

Comment: @DileepKumar, As of now, I don't think, you have a workaround here. [You will need to follow strictly with the regular in-app purchase flow.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) Per your current plan, display the in-app purchase options.

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar Thanks I check and follow the in-App purchase concept.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your app have **In-App purchase** that is unlocking the app features or giving the advance feature to the user by the payment.

To apply this feature in your app, you must have to implement [Apple in-app-purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) in your app. But in your scenario you implement any other external payment source of credit card or debit which is not allowed by the apple.

To solve this rejection either implement In-app-purchase or remove this feature.

Apple rejection reasons description -> https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/

Comment: thanks for answer...But I want to clarify something I have created subscription plan UI ,Billing UI and credit card payment UI in my iOS App and through the services  I am sending data to my local server they are using PayPal gateway for payment  in Backend and completing Payment.and after payment successful they are notify me.so All these things we are handling through the web services..pls guide me

Comment: @DileepKumar Actually you didnt get me properly. You'r right with your logic. Now try to think like apple. When you use paypal then your transaction directly affected to owner account. but in case of in-app apple deduct the 30% then send your rest of money in your account.

Comment: Thanks I check and follow the in-App purchase concept